# Complex Dice Calculator

Tags: android, calculator

Good afternoon. I am pretty new to the whole Programming thing. However in an effort to learn something I've been building an RPG Dice rolling app on Android Studio. My question is how would I go about creating a complex Dice Roller, where the user manually enters what they want to roll via an edittext field.

Ie. 3d20+2d6+2 =

Comment: My issues lies in where to even begin. Right now I have a simple Dice Roller using r.nextint(#) for each of the simple rolls. I have also implemented the bottom bar navigation so each of my classes extend fragment. I know how I want it to work using the edittext fields, but not where to start. I am more than capable of tweaking code to fit my needs once I have a starting place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [break the pieces of the user input down into tokens.](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

> Parse on "+":
>
> 1) 3d20
>   2) 2d6
>   3) 2

```
String[] tokens = "3d20+2d6+2".split("+");
```

Then, you need to break each of those tokens down into more pieces.

> Parse on "d":
>
> 1a) 3
>     1b) 20
>
> 2a) 2
>     2b) 6
>   
>   3) 2

```
for (int x=0; x<tokens.length; x++) {
     String[] roll = tokens[x].split("d");
     // do something with roll[0]
     // and roll[1] if roll.length > 1
}
```